# How to execute multiple .sh files in different directories using *.sh

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I need to write a shell script which can execute all `.sh` files if they exist in a directory pattern. Something like:

```
##!/bin/bash
sh /var/scripts/*/my_*.inc.sh
```

But the above script executes only just one file; the first file which happens (seems chosen by the latest modification date) which is not my point. I need all files matching the rule to be executed.

Comment: No time for a complete answer, but also suggest you look at run-parts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason that your code does not work is because of what happens when a filename globbing pattern expands.

The pattern would expand to a *list* of matching pathnames.  The code in your script would call `sh` with this list. This means it would execute the first matching name as the script and give the other names as *arguments* to that script:

```
sh /var/scripts/dir/my_first.inc.sh /var/scripts/dir/my_second.inc.sh /var/scripts/dir/my_third.inc.sh
```

Instead, just iterate over the matching names:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

for name in /var/scripts/*/my_*.inc.sh; do
    sh "$name"
done
```

This assumes that each of the matching names is a script that should be executed by `sh` (not `bash`).  If the individual files are executable and has a proper `#!`-line, then remove the `sh` from the invocation of the script in the loop above.  If the files are "dot scripts", i.e. script that should be sourced, then replace `sh` by `.` instead to have the script execute in the current script's environment.

Note that the script above can be an `sh` script (`#!/bin/sh`) as it does not use any `bash` features. If the other script are "dot scripts", then you may obviously have to change this to `#!/bin/bash` or whatever other interpreter is needed to source the scripts.

Answer (score 5):

A `.inc.sh` extension suggests those `.inc.sh` file should be *included*, or in other words, that their contents should be evaluated as shell code by *one* shell interpreter, so that that same shell interpreter can execute some other code with the *functions*, *variables*, *aliases*... defined in those files available.

`bash`'s syntax is mostly backward compatible with the `sh` syntax, especially when its POSIX mode is enabled (`bash` is actually a `sh` interpreter when invoked as `sh`), so even though those functions are presumably written in `sh` language, you should still be able to have a `bash` interpreter interpret them.

One notable difference between `bash` (when not in POSIX mode) and `sh` is that `bash` doesn't enable `alias` expansion in scripts. That can be worked around though by setting the `expand_aliases` option or the `posix` option, so you can do:

```
#! /bin/bash -
set -o posix # increase POSIX sh compatibility, some but not all bash-specific
             # extensions are still available.

for file in /var/scripts/*/my_*.inc.sh; do
  . "$file"
done

# rest of the code that uses the functions/variables, etc defined
# in the files sourced above with the "." special builtin
```

Note that if there's no matching file, the `.` command will fail when trying to source a non-existing file called literally `/var/scripts/*/my_*.inc.sh` and exit the shell.

If instead in that case you wanted to not do anything you could do:

```
shopt -s nullglob
files=(/var/scripts/*/my_*.inc.sh)
shopt -u nullglob

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
  command . "$file"
done
```

With `nullglob`, globs with no match expand to the empty list instead of the unexpanded pattern. With the `command` prefix, failure of special builtins like `.` (like when `$file` is not readable) doesn't cause the shell to exit (and error should still be reported).

To look for `.inc.sh` files recursively instead of just the subdirs of `/var/scripts`, you could use the `globstar` option to enable the `**` operator:

```
shopt -s nullglob globstar
files=(/var/scripts/**/my_*.inc.sh)
shopt -u nullglob globstar
```

In any case, directory and files whose name starts with `.` (hidden ones) are omitted. Use the `dotglob` option if you want to include the,

Obviously, if any of the sourced scripts calls `exit` or `exec` or has a syntax error or any of the special builtins called within fail, that will also exit the script.

Answer (score 3):

The safest way to iterate over files in shell scripts (including bash), is to use pathname expansion (globbing) in a for loop. The correct code is:

```
for file in /var/scripts/*/my_*.inc.sh
do
  echo "Executing $file"
  "$file"
done
```

This will handle paths and filenames with special characters such as spaces, asterisks, newlinews, etc.

If you want to do recursive search, or use options that globbing is not capable of providing, find may be used with the `-exec` option (bellow assumes recent GNU find):

```
find a/ -executable -type f -name '*.sh' -exec {} \;
```

If find is still necessary, but you and to execute multiple commands on each file, `read` can be used, but you should careful with the options to handle all filenames (bellow assumes bash and GNU find):

```
#!/bin/bash
find a/ -executable -type f -name '*.sh' -print0 |
  while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file
  do
    echo "Executing $file"
    "$file"
  done
```

Comment: The earlier claim (now edited away) that the other solutions won't work with spaces etc. in filenames seems not to apply to the xargs solution.  I tested it on Ubuntu 18.04 (bash 4.4.18, findutils (xargs) 4.6.0).  I don't know whether it might break on some other systems, though.

Comment: @JaripekkaJuhala: It works for spaces but not newline characters (yes they are valid in filenames).

Comment: Sorry, tested again. You're right, newlines won't work :(

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether it is the best solution, but `xargs` can in general be used for thing like this:

```
ls /var/scripts/*/my_*.inc.sh | xargs -I {} sh {}
```

As pointed out by @user000001, this won't work for filenames with a newline character.

Comment: The problem is not limited to newline characters. single quote (apostrophe), double quote and backslash are also a problem. Also note that the stdin of those scripts is also affected (will be either /dev/null or the pipe depending on that xargs implementation).

Comment: What if there are spaces in the script file names?

Comment: @user000001, not really, `-L 1` runs one command from each line of input, but those lines are still split into words that make up separate arguments to the command. With `-I {}`, there's no splitting within the lines, but leading whitespace is stripped (at least with POSIX compliant implementations, not busybox's and with the list of which characters are considered whitespace varying with the implementation). IMO, `xargs` is only usable with `-r0` (non-standard).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thanks, I did some tests before commenting, but they didn't include *leading* whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop to iterate (recursively) through all shell files in a path found with `find`, like so:

```
for i in $(find /var/scripts/ -type f -name '*.sh')
  do sh "$i"
done
```

Comment: This has issues with files that has spaces in their names. It may also find other files than what the user in the question wants to find (note that they mentioned a very specific globbing pattern).

Comment: About that, see [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Comment: Thank you @StéphaneChazelas